# help with OCR application - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr

I'm really need your help, I'm desperate.

I'm trying to build an OCR application and I'm facing some problems that I can't solve alone.
for now I'm cutting the plate form the image and doing some filtering to reduce the noise.
for example, this is the plate after cutting it from the image and after filtering:

[image]

now because that the plate is in angle and because that there is still noise (like above the numbers 9 and 3), the identification process(using corr2) is giving me the wrong numbers.

eg:

[image]

as you see the only problem is in the numbers 9 and 3(at the left side) where the noise is disturbing.

I thought to stretch the image so that each number will fit all the square (without the black lines at the top), but I can't find any method to do this that it will work for every image.

**EDIT:** this is the results from the corr2 function, I marked in red the results of the numbers 9 and 3.   [image]

please give me an idea or working solution...

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip, convolution is not a particularly robust or efficient method for this problem. You should look into machine learning topics like neural networks or support vector machines. A lot of relevant info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850717/what-are-some-popular-ocr-algorithms

Comment: consider blurring the training image (supposing the second row is your training template) so that the *darkness* and *thickness* of the digits' strokes are similar to your input. As for the first digit (9 misrecognized as 1), are you sure its correlation is positive? For this particular input, can you list its correlation toward all templates (from 0 to 9) so that we'll see how close it is to being misrecognized? Finally, you may also try [Linear Discriminant Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) or Eigenface, it's a easier starting point.

Comment: Methink you should recheck your master images ... Also, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777677/license-plate-recognition-determining-color-range-for-pixel-comparison/4778495#4778495, perhaps you can get some inspiration

Answer (score 1):

You may pre-process the image you posted in a previous question:

[image]

with something like: (code in Mathematica)

```
Dilation[
   DeleteSmallComponents[
        Pruning[
            Thinning@
                Binarize[
                   ColorSeparate[
                      ColorNegate@yourColorImage, "HSB"][[3]], 
                .92], 
        10], 
   30],
3]
```

Result:

[image]

Now your OCR should pass without much trouble, like this one:

[image]

**Edit**

A step by step procedure posted [**in your other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312514/clean-noise-from-an-image-with-matlab/6259407#6259407)